# SQL Error when I use distinct order by upper/lower

Tags: sql, postgresql

This does not work in postgres 8.4:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM mytable
  ORDER BY UPPER(col1);
```

but this works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM mytable
  ORDER BY col1;
```

I know it might be bit confusing for the database whether to apply DISTINCT first and then UPPER or first convert to UPPER and then apply DISTINCT. Based on order how it applies one may get different result. Not sure if SQL standard says anything in this regards.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What error message are you getting?  If it's what I think it is, you might be able to use this query - SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(col1), col1 FROM mytable ORDER BY UPPER(col1);

Comment: the error I am getting is: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Comment: @BrianHoover: I suppose you post your comment as answer so the OP can accept it. It obviously solved the question for the OP.

Answer (score 5):

Many SQL engines only allow you to sort on columns that are being selected.  So the fix to add the UPPER(col1) to the select.

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(col1), col1 FROM mytable ORDER BY UPPER(col1)
```

Comment: The [`DISTINCT` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) and `ORDER BY` have to agree on the **left-most** columns. It is ok and useful in many cases to add *additional* `ORDER BY` columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across the same problem and in my particular context the following was simpler to implement:

```
select * from (select distinct col1 from mytable) x order by upper(col1)
```

I did not bother doing any performance testing (in my case the data volume is fairly low), but possibly this might even improve speed as the sorting may happen on significantly less data (Postgres doc says that sorting happens before applying DISTINCT, while the way above we first DISTINCT, then sort).